# go scan Postgres array_agg

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a one-to-many relationship in postgres (Event has many EventUser), and would like to scan and store into a struct `Event`.

```
// EventUser struct
type EventUser struct {
    ID              int64
    CheckedIn       bool
    PaidAmount      float32
}

// Event struct
type Event struct {
    ID         int64  `json:"id"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    StartTime  string `json:"startTime"`
    EventUsers string
}
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name, events."startTime", e."eventUsers" as "eventUsers"
FROM "Events" as events
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT events.id as id, array_to_json(array_agg(eu.*)) as "eventUsers"
        FROM "EventUsers" as eu
        JOIN "Events" AS "events" ON events.id = eu."eventId"
        WHERE eu.status = 'RESERVED'
        GROUP BY events.id
    ) AS e USING (id)
WHERE events.status = 'COMPLETED'
```

The query returns this:

```
{
  id: 2,
  name: "2 Events are 48 days from now",
  startTime: 1590471343345,
  eventUsers: [
    {
      id: 2,
      checkedIn: false,
      paidAmount: 8
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      checkedIn: false, 
      paidAmount: 8,
    },
  ],
};
```

This is what I am trying to do, which directly scan each item under `eventUsers` into struct, and store in the `Event`'s struct.

```
got := []Event{}

for rows.Next() {
    var r Event
    err = rows.Scan(&r.ID, &r.Name, &r.StartTime, &r.EventUsers)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I think I could achieve this by storing the array as a string and then `unmarshal` it.

What I want is something similar to `sql.NullString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a slice type that implements the [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface. Note that when you pass an instance of a type that implements Scanner to a `(*sql.Rows).Scan` or `(*sql.Row).Scan` call, the impelmenter's `Scan` method will be invoked automatically.

```
type EventUserList []*EventUser

func (list *EventUserList) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if data, ok := src.([]byte); ok && len(data) > 0 {
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, list); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then, assuming that the `e."eventUsers"` in the select query is a json *array*, you could use it like this:

```
// EventUser struct
type EventUser struct {
    ID         int64
    CheckedIn  bool
    PaidAmount float32
}

// Event struct
type Event struct {
    ID         int64         `json:"id"`
    Name       string        `json:"name"`
    StartTime  string        `json:"startTime"`
    EventUsers EventUserList `json:"eventUsers"`
}

// ...

var events []*Event
for rows.Next() {
    e := new(Event)
    if err := rows.Scan(&e.ID, &e.Name, &e.StartTime, &e.EventUsers); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    events = append(events, e)
}
```

Comment: Is this the polymorphism?

Comment: @leogoesger I'm not sure if polymorphism is the precise technical term, but wikipedia's section on go's interface system mentions that it provides "runtime polymorphism" so yeah, maybe that's what one would call it.